# Android app crashes when click button

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new android developer :D I am having a small problem with my app which is when I click on a button to move to another activity, the app crashes. I tried some solutions such declaring buttons at the top before clickListner and modifying intent but non worked. Can Someone help me please?

MainActivity.java

package com.example.geocalc;

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Button CiButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CircleButton);
        final Button CyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CylinderButton);
        final Button CuButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CubeButton);
        final Button TriButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.TriangleButton);
        final Button SpButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SphereButton);
        final Button SqButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SquareButton);
        final Button RecButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.RectangleButton);
        final Button RPButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.RectangularPrismButton);
        CiButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CircleActivity.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

CircleActivity.java (The activity I am trying to reach):

```
package com.example.geocalc;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class CircleActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_circle);
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CalculateButton);
        final EditText radiustext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RadiusText);
        final EditText areatext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.AreaText);
        final EditText circtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CircumferenceText);
        double radius;
        final double area;
        final double circumference;
        radius= Double.parseDouble(radiustext.getText().toString());
        area = Math.round((Math.PI*Math.pow(radius,2.0)*Math.pow(10,4))/Math.pow(10, 4));
         circumference = Math.round ((Math.PI*2*radius*Math.pow(10, 4))/Math.pow(10, 4));
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                  areatext.setText(Double.toString(area));
                  circtext.setText(Double.toString(circumference));
             }
         });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.circle, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Android Manifist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.geocalc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CircleActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_circle" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Post the stack trace from logcat.  That will tell you what went wrong.

Comment: Have you declared it in the manifest , please post the logcat message .

Comment: The Log cat is not displaying any messages

Comment: @Kito312 When the app crashes there always is a logcat output.

Comment: @Gumbo I know that but there are no messages

Comment: @Kito312 the code you have written, is probably showing part of what you are trying to do. As pointed out below the number format can be wrong, or the layout file can be incorrect. For anyone of us to be able to help, please fix the code snippet above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current activity tries to calculate the circumference in the `onCreate` method, and display it in a `TextView`. However, it may fail on the line

```
radius= Double.parseDouble(radiustext.getText().toString());
```

if you don't **have a valid number set in that `EditText` by default**.

It can be fixed by setting a default text to your `radiustext` member (do the `Double.parseDouble` won't throw exception).

But I assume you'd like this circumference to be calculated on demand, so you should rather put your calculation inside the click handler as well:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        try
        {
            final double radius = Double.parseDouble(radiustext.getText().toString());
            final double area = Math.round((Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2.0) * Math.pow(10, 4)) / Math.pow(10, 4));
            final double circumference = Math.round((Math.PI * 2 * radius * Math.pow(10, 4)) / Math.pow(10, 4));
            areatext.setText(Double.toString(area));
            circtext.setText(Double.toString(circumference));
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            Log.e("Click", "Exception caught in .onClick", e);
        }
    }
});
```

The `try-catch` will handle any `NumberFormatException`s that still may be thrown.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked! I'd like to know why it didn't work at the beginning

Comment: Because you made the calculations only once, when the activity has been created (inside the `onCreate` method). By that time, you didn't have any value set in your `radiusText` view, so parsing its value as a Double failed. With the fix you calculate the circumference every time the button is clicked, with freshly set radius values.